# Requests library Unicode error for ampersand in the Payload

Tags: python

I am trying to make an api call like this

```
 def getSearchResults(self, sid):
        headers = {'accept': 'application/xml'}
        payload = {'output_mode': 'csv' , 'count' : 0 }
        baseurl = "%s://%s/%s/%s/results" % (self.protocol, self.host, 'services/search/jobs', sid)
        response = ""
        try:
            t = time.time()
            response = requests.get(baseurl,params=payload, auth=(self.userName, self.password), headers=headers,verify=False, timeout=self.request_timeout_sec)
            #print("Splunk Results API URL '%s' took %s secs.Response: '%s'" % ( baseurl, str(round(time.time()-t, 3)), str(response)))
            print(response.url)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(str(ex))
        return response.text
```

But I get this error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 330854: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This problem happens when i give second key value pair in the parload

Comment: The error is for U+2013 EN DASH, not ampersand.

Comment: did you check `print(response.content)` ? Did you check (in Google) what char has code `u'\u2013'` and where you have it in content ? Maybe contents use encoding different then `utf-8` and it has problem to convert it.

Comment: ```print(response.content)``` gives me what i want but with the above error and I am new to python  , so i dont know anything

Comment: You need to extract and provide a [mcve]. Concerning your case, it would e.g. help if you said explicitly where the error happens, included the backtrace and hardcoded what you get as result, so people don't have to make the same query. Further, make sure you do a little research about the error you got and possible reasons for it. There are literally hundreds of questions with similar errors here! Also, as a new user here, make sure you took the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try passing unicode url as request. Something like

```
unicode_url = u'https://test.com/test/?param1=1234'
```

Comment: no that gives string do not have an attribute .text

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys I solved this by

`return response.text.encode("utf-8")`

Thanks everyone !